# How can I get the returned value from a function that's being threaded?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have this function

```
Public Function GetPage(ByVal dlURL As String) As String
    Dim S As String = ""
    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(dlURL)
    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
    Using Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
        S = Reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
    Return S
End Function
```

And it works on its own. However, I'm trying to thread it like this

```
Dim threadRes
Dim dlThread = New Thread(Sub() threadRes = GetPage("http://www.dubstaphone.com/hub/betaversion.txt"))
dlThread.Start()
```

And threadRes is a blank variable. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** The function works on its own when I do GetPage(string) and not part of a thread.

Comment: That's rather fundamental, you can't get the result until the thread is completed.  Defeating the point of using a thread.  Get ahead with [Async/Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant The editor isn't recognizing Async when I put it in front of the function. What am I doing wrong?